# Как передать объект в компонент из вычисляемого свойства

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Дан массив со спортивными матчами в формате JSON, который я передаю в файл компонента из хранилища Vuex (через action  loadGameData).
Затем мне нужно совершить определенные действия с этим массивом, а именно – подсчитать количество матчей каждой команды и вывести данные в виде таблицы, где каждая строка выглядит так: название команды – число матчей.

Я сделала это через вычисляемое свойство countGames(). В итоге внутри вычисляемого свойства у меня создается новый объект result1:

```
 { 
    {team_name: "Lokomotiv", matches: 3}, 
    {team_name: "Spartak", matches: 2} 
 }
```

Как мне теперь вывести эти значения в  таблицу с классом "computed-data"?

```
<template>
  <div class="teams_table">
        <button @click='showTeamsTable = !showTeamsTable'> Show teams table </button>  

        <!-- здесь выводятся напрямую данные из JSON-->
        <table class="data-json" v-show='showTeamsTable'>
          <tr>
            <th>Date </th>
            <th>Teams:</th>
            <th>Score:</th> 
          </tr>
          <tr v-for="i in games">
            <td> {{ i.game_date_start }} </td>
            <td> {{ i.t1_name }} / {{ i.t2_name }}</td>
            <td> {{ i.team_1_goals_quantity}} : {{i.team_2_goals_quantity}}</td>
          </tr>           
        </table>

        <!-- здесь нужно сгенерировать таблицу с названиями команд и количеством матчей каждой-->
        <table class="computed-data">
          <tr>
            <th>Team Name</th>          
            <th>Total team's matches</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> ??? </td> <!--тут должен быть result1.team_name (для каждой команды), вычисленный в countGames()-->
            <td> ??? </td>  <!--тут должен быть result1.matches (для каждой команды), вычисленный в countGames()-->
          </tr>           
        </table>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {  
  name: "teams_table", 
  data () {
   return {
     showTeamsTable: true 
   }
  },
  created() {    
     this.$store.dispatch('loadGameData')// вызываю из хранилища VueX JSON с данными матчей  
  },   
  computed: {       
      ...mapGetters([
        'games',
        'gamedatestart'
        ]),           
      countGames() { 
            var data = this.$store.getters.games;               
            var arr1 = []; 
            var obj1 = {};   

            //Нахожу число матчей для каждой команды путем подсчета вхождений названия команды в JSON
            function getMatches() { 
                    for (var i in data) {        
                          obj1[data[i].t1_name] = (obj1[data[i].t1_name] || 0) + 1;
                          obj1[data[i].t2_name] = (obj1[data[i].t2_name] || 0) + 1
                    };      
                    Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(el, data) {
                        arr1.push( [ el, obj1[el]] );                   
                    });    
                    console.log(arr1);  //создаю новый массив вида ["Lokomotiv", 2],["Spartak", 3]                           
                 }; 
            getMatches(); 

            var result1 = arr1.map(
                  ([team_name, matches]) => ({team_name, matches})      
            );         
            return result1; // создаю объект вида { {team_name: "Lokomotiv", matches: 3}, {team_name: "Spartak", matches: 2} }
        },        
  }, 
}
```

Comment: с помощью директивы `v-for`: `v-for="item in countGames"`

Comment: Действительно, как все оказалось просто! Спасибо большое, @Дмытрык